# Angular issue about autocomplete of material design

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created an autocomplete controls with `http api` getting data.

But `<mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region.name">` is throw an error like this: 
`Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

I have checked the data returns `Region[]` in `method 1` , line 52.

And I google for solution `method 2`, it works but not able to work with `loading indicator`

I hope someone can give a hand to me. Thanks.

My code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89p1pm

I have 3 questions to ask:

- error popup
- method 1: not show list of countries
- how to deal with `Observable with loading indicator`

## Method 1

```
form.get('region').valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  tap(r => this.isLoading = true),
  switchMap(inputCountry => 
    this.regionService.getRegions().pipe(
      map( regions => {
        return regions.filter(region => region.name.indexOf(inputCountry) >= 0)
      })
    )
  )
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('onRegionChanged: data', data);
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.regions = data;
})
```

## Method 2

```
form.get('region').valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      tap(r => this.isLoading$.next(true)),
    ).subscribe(inputCountry => {
      this.regions$ = this.regionService.getRegions().pipe(
        tap(r => this.isLoading$.next(false)),
        map(regions => regions.filter(region => region.name.indexOf(inputCountry) >= 0))
      )
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbravx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Your issue is that you're iterating over an empty array. Just add it to your condition.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading && regions?.length">
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but when i load your code, console log still have an error `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: @johnchan that's on me, I didn't refresh the page and thought there was no error. I'm taking another look at it now !

Comment: thanks, but I have still some questions to ask, written in question, like why `method 1` do not show list of country, and how to handle async data with loading indicator

Comment: Look, I answered your question but I'm not your teacher. If you have specific questions, please ask new ones, don't message me everytime you have one and edit your question ... As far as I'm concerned, this one is answered !